# Setter and Getter for variable using objc/runtime.h

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter

I have good Setter and Getter code for Object. How do same for BOOL using objc/runtime.h like here?
objc_getAssociatedObject require object

```
.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface UITableView (Additions)
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *allowReplenishment;
@end

.m
#import "UITableView+Additions.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITableView (Additions)

- (NSNumber *)allowReplenishment {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(allowReplenishment));
}

- (void)setAllowReplenishment:(NSNumber *)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(allowReplenishment), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare your `bool` property 
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAllowReplenishment, just create the object in the setter instead, as needed:

```
- (void)setIsAllowReplenishment:(BOOL)isAllowReplenishment
    {
        NSNumber *isBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isAllowReplenishment];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(isAllowReplenishment), isBool, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
        }

        - (BOOL)isAllowReplenishment
            {
                NSNumber *isBool = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(isAllowReplenishment));
                return isBool.boolValue;
    }
```

Comment: Using the SEL as the context is dangerous, as this address is accessible to other code (Apple could be using that, or your superclass etc.). In general, a better idea would be to declare your own context global `static void* kIsAllowReplenishmentAssociatedObjectContext = &kIsAllowReplenishmentAssociatedObjectContext;` and pass that as the context in the getter/setter. This variable just contains its own address, so you can pass it like any old constant, but it is a unique value because nothing else in your app can occupy the same memory.